# Is "my something of choice" the same as "something of my choice"?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

Would like to know if it's wrong to use "my something of choice"? Does the phrase have the same meaning as "something of my choice"?

Comment: flamengo, welcome to ELU; however, since it's obvious you're asking this because you're learning English, perhaps you should ask it at our site specifically for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Marthaª, I think not. I was about to answer this question, when I realised that I didn't understand the difference either.

Comment: "my something of choice" == constant favourite; "something of my choice" == a one-off choice from a selection

Comment: @flamengo This question has been open for a while. If the answers you received have satisfied your needs, please accept one of them. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two phrases have slightly different connotations.

"My something of choice" implies a personal favorite or habitual preference. E.g. "The [golden gun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_with_the_Golden_Gun_%28film%29) is *his weapon of choice*."

"Something of my choice" implies getting to choose from a specific set. It is appropriate for describing a momentary decision. E.g. "The steak comes with *a side of your choice*: soup of the day, Caesar salad, or steamed vegetables."

Comment: I think your connotations explain very clearly, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase [*the something of choice*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/choice) means

> the thing that most people prefer to use in a particular situation:
>   *Penicillin remains the drug of choice in treating this disease.*

In the same vein, ***my*** something of choice is what *you* prefer to use in a given situation, e.g., "*The Porsche Panamera is my car of choice for long journeys.*"

On the other hand, *something of my choice* is something you do because you want to, not because you have to: "*Bicycling thirty miles to work is of my choice.*"